# fractional Brownian motion is not a semimartingale. How to apply Ergodic theorem in the proof of this theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Here is the **proof** of the theorem. **I couldn't understand how to apply Ergodic theorem in this proof.** 
Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a fractional Brownian motion with self-similar
parameter $H\in(0,1)$. We know that when $H = \frac{1}{2}$, fractional Brownian motion is
in fact a standard Brownian motion and hence a semimartingale.
\paragraph{}Now fix the parameter $H$ and consider for $p > 0$ fixed
\begin{equation}
Y_{n,p}:= \sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|X_{j2^{-n}}-X_{(j-1)2^{-n}}|^p\big(2^n\big)^{pH-1}
\end{equation}
From self-similarity property we obtain that (3.6) has (for each n) the same law
as
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|2^{-nH}X_j-2^{-nH}X_{j-1}|^p\big(2^n\big)^{pH-1}&=&\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|X_j-X_{j-1}|^p2^{-npH}\big(2^n\big)^{pH-1} \nonumber \\
&=&2^{-n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|X_j-X_{j-1}|^p.
\end{eqnarray}
Noticing that the sequence $\big(X_k - X_{k-1}\big)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is stationary and ergodic, the ergodic theorem tells us that
$$
\tilde{Y}_{n,p}:=2^{-n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|X_j-X_{j-1}|^p\rightarrow E|X_1-X_0|^p=:\gamma_p \quad (n\rightarrow\infty)
$$
almost surely and in $L^1$. Hence,

$$Y_{n,p}\overset {d}{\rightarrow}\gamma_p \quad (n\rightarrow\infty)$$

and therefore $Y_{n,p}\overset {P}{\rightarrow}\gamma_p$.Hence,
\begin{equation}
V_{n,p}:=\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|X_{j2^{-n}}-X_{j-1(2^{-n})}|^p\rightarrow \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{if} \quad pH > 1 \\
    \infty & \quad \text{if}  \quad pH < 1 
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
If $H > \frac{1}{2}$, we can choose $p\in(H^{-1},2$) such that $V_{n,p}\rightarrow 0$ in probability, and therefore almost surely down a fast subsequence. This implies that the quadratic variation of $X$ is zero, and so (if $X$ were to be a semimartingale) $X$ must be a finite-variation process. But since for $p\in(1,H^{-1})$,$V_p := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} V_{n,p}$ is almost surely infinite, and (by scaling) the p-variation on any interval is infinite almost surely, $X$ can not be finite variation. If $H <\frac{1}{2}$, we can choose $p > 2$ such that $pH < 1$, and the p-variation of $X$ on $[0,1]$ (and hence on any fixed interval) must be infinite. This contradicts the almost-sure finiteness of the quadratic variation of $X$, assuming $X$ is a semimartingale. In either way, if $H\neq\frac{1}{2}$, $X$ is not a semimartingale.$\square$

Comment: The title of your question is rather misleading. The proof actually shows that a fractional BM is *not* a semimartingale unless $H=1/2$.

Comment: And which part do you not understand? That the sequence is ergodic and stationary or how the ergodic theorem is applied or...?

Comment: I want to know that how Ergodic theorem is applied here? thank you for your comment, I corrected the title.

Comment: So could you add the statement of the ergodic theorem which you want to apply? Or is it not contained in the book? And again: Do you understand that the sequence is ergodic and stationary?

Comment: This proof is from this article. "Arbitrage with fractional Brownian motion" by Rogers. Other books are mentioned this proof. I couldn't find another resource with more explanation. I know the sequence is stationary but I dont know why it s ergodic.

Comment: this article is available here http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9965.00025/pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261730/applying-ergodic-theorem-on-fractional-brownian-motion

Comment: the same question is asked as mine, but it still doesn't make sense for me. Particularly this $X_0=|B_H(1)|^p$

Comment: ... then just write a comment to his answer and ask him?

Comment: yes, thank you.