# Is every continuous process an Ito process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I see sometimes in Financial Maths literature that we have covered all continuous processes when assuming the following dynamics: $dX_t = \mu_t \, dt + \sigma_t \, dW_t$.

I can formulate my question in two ways and I am not sure they are entirely equivalent:

1. Is every continuous process an Ito process?
2. Can every continuous process be decomposed in a Brownian part and a finite variation part (Semimartingale)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: After some thought, I think the answer to both questions is no and one counter-example could be $X(t,\omega)=W(t, \omega_0)$ which is continuous but not a locale martingale and with infinite variation and can be shown as not a semimartingale.

Comment: Pretty sure Ito processes are Markov. There are plenty of processes which are not Markov, take for instance the linear interpolation of some discrete-time random walk, or $B_t+B_{t+1}$ for a BM $B$, etc.

Comment: I don't think every Ito process is Markov e.g. $dX_t = \left(\int_0^t X_s\, ds\right)\, dB_t$

Comment: Oh you're right, if you allow $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to depend on the whole trajectory up to time $t$ then there's no reason for $X$ to be Markov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, continuous processes fail to be semimartingales (and hence Itô processes). A classical example is the [fractional Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) with Hurst index $H \neq \frac{1}{2}$. The process is a Gaussian process and has continuous sample paths, but it fails to be a semimartingale (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034050/fractional-brownian-motion-is-not-a-semimartingale-how-to-apply-ergodic-theorem)).

Financial Mathematics tends to ignore the fact that the world is not governed by Brownian motion (and not even by the much larger class of continuous processes)...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes perfect sense. Can you maybe confirm that the process $X(t, w) = W(t, w0)$ is also such a counter-example?

Comment: @OthmanNejjar You have to be careful about picking one particular sample path. This particular sample path might be very nice (e.g. differentiable) and hence a semimartingale. For instance if you consider the canonical model, i.e. $W(t,\omega) = \omega(t)$ for $\omega \in C[0,\infty)$, then for $\omega_0(t) := 0$ the sample path $W(t,\omega_0)=0$ is clearly a semimartingale.

Comment: OK got it but my understanding is that there exists a sample path that has our required properties because of the usual almost surely properties of a Brownian motion.

Comment: @OthmanNejjar Yeah that's correct.