# Why is fractional stochastic integral no semimartingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I have problems to under stand the following thing:

I totally see that the fractional Brownian Motion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) is no semimartingale hor $H\neq \frac{1}{2}$, since increments are not independent.
But, I often read that it is possible to represent the fractional BM as a stochastic integral in something like that form: $$ X_t = C \int (t-s)^{H-\frac{1}{2}}dW_s $$, where W is a standard BM.
Why should that integral not be a local martingale?

thanks for any help

Comment: The problem is the dependance on $t$ in the integral. More generally if $$X_t(\omega )=\int_0^t f(t,s,\omega )dW_s(\omega ),$$ then $X=(X_t)$ won't be a martingale (unless if $f(t,s,\cdot )=g(s,\cdot )$).

Comment: Thank you Surb that helps me. Do you have any source or something for me to read about that?

Comment: I think it's quite straightforward, no ? Just consider $f(t,s,\cdot )=g(t)h(s,\cdot )$ where $\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t h(s,\omega )^2ds\right]<\infty $. Then, if $t>s>0$,  $$\mathbb E\left[\int_0^tf(t,u,\omega )dW_u\mid \mathcal F_s\right]=g(t)\int_0^s h(u,\cdot )dW_u$$ $$\neq g(s)\int_0^s h(u,\cdot )dW_u.$$ Therefore, it's not a martingale.

Comment: Oh yes, really straightforward. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

We let $B_{H}(t):= C \int (t-s)^{H-\frac{1}{2}}dW_s$ and follow [Arbitrage with fractional Brownian motion](http://www.long-memory.com/fractional-brownian-motion/Rogers1997.pdf). The key is that a [semimartingale always has finite quadratic variation](https://planetmath.org/quadraticvariationofasemimartingale), and if its quadratic variation is zero, then it is of bounded variation.

Consider the interval $[0,1]$ on which is defined the fractional Brownian motion $B_{H}$, and consider its partitions $\pi_n = \{t^n_k = \frac{k}{2^{n}} : 0\le 1\le 2^{n}\},\ n\in\mathbb N$ and

$$ V_p^{n}(B_{H}) =  \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}} |B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k)|^p. $$

By the [ergodic theorem applied to fBM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261730/applying-ergodic-theorem-on-fractional-brownian-motion?rq=1)

$$\frac{V_p^{n}(B_{H})}{2^{n(1-pH)}}\to E[|B_{H}(1)-B_{H}(0)|^{p}]=c_{p}\neq 0.$$

Therefore,
$$ V_p(B_{H}) =\begin{cases}
        \infty, & \text{if }\ pH < 1, \\
        0,       & \text{if }\ pH > 1.
    \end{cases}
$$

If $H<\frac{1}{2}$, we get $V_{2}(B_{H})=+\infty$. If $H>\frac{1}{2}$, then we get that $V_{2}(B_{H})=0$ and $V_{1}(B_{H})=+\infty$ but this contradicts that if a semimartingale has zero quadratic variation, it least has finite 1-variation.